# Change the username of in PS1 to any arbatrary strings temporally

Tags: terminator, virtual-console, ps1

I set my terminal prompt as:

```
$ echo $PS1
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]:\n$
```

It display as:

```
me@alpha:/:
```

How could change the username of me to any arbitrary name temporally?

For example change it to spirit@alpah:/：

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *parameter substitution*:

```
PS1="${PS1//\\u/spirit}"
```

To reverse it,

```
PS1="${PS1//spirit/\\u}"
```